# Hibernate entity class is not picking up

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to use hibernate with annotations. I annotated my class with @Entity (Made sure that this is javax.persistance.Entity instead of Hibernate's entity) and @Table.

When I am trying to query the table with

```
session.createQuery("from HibernateMatchedInvoiceItem").list()
```

But this is failing with following exception

```
caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: HibernateMatchedInvoiceItem is not mapped [from HibernateMatchedInvoiceItem]
```

my session factory is defined as follows.

```
   <bean id="SessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      parent="AbstractSessionFactory" depends-on="AppConfigHelper">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
     </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
```

I didn't define persistant.xml file. Is it the reason behind this exception? 
My doubt is that, since everything hibernate wants(database connection & class mapping) is specified through configuration and annotations, why do we need to specify persistance.xml file explicitly?

Comment: Are you sure that HibernateMatchedInvoiceItem table is created in your database?

Comment: HibernateMatchedInvoiceItem class is annotated with @Table(name="matched_invoices") and matched_invoices table has some rows. This is giving results if I am using simple jdbc template instead of using hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using annotations then you have to use class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"

Example :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>package.classname</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: Bean is not acepting annotatedClasses property. Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'annotatedClasses' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'annotatedClasses' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html

Comment: You should carefully check your hibernate entity supports the java bean convention.